# Count characters in HTML

Tags: c#, html, ckeditor

How I can count characters that are in a CKEditor using C#.

```
string test = ckAdd.Text;
string testd = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(test);
int times = testd.Count(char.IsLetter);
```

Comment: Okay and what is the problem, this will count every letter in the testd string.

Comment: hi lets say my input is (aaa) the output when i debug will be (&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;aaa&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;)  25 characters instead of 3

Comment: I solved it,i changed from Encode to Decode,thanks.